# Fetching Specific TimeZone time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm working in India and I want to get the time details in Europe/London.
Here in the below code, I have given European/London time zone for initializing the DateTimeFormat.
After initialization I was unable to fetch the value for time individually as hours(24hrs format), minutes and seconds.

If I try to fetch the hours value using resolvedOptions(), then it's yielding as "2-digit".

I want to print the hours in 24hr format like "**22**" :12 :02

Is there any way to modify the code?

Or else is there any other way to fetch the values of time individually into the hours, minutes and seconds.

```js
function getEuropeTime() {
  let options = {
      timeZone: 'Europe/London',
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
      second: 'numeric',
      hour12: false,
    },
    formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options);
  var date = formatter.format(new Date())
  var usedOptions = formatter.resolvedOptions();
  console.log(usedOptions.hour);
  console.log(date);
}

getEuropeTime();
```

Comment: Well, never used it, but the manual talks about a timezone as the first argument where have [] and I think the timeZone variable is the time of the Date you are passing in.   Have you tried using a ; instead of , after the options initialization?

Comment: You are effectively passing the browser default language as the "locale", which nearly always overrides the *hour12* option. Consider using [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) with a language code that has 24 hour time to get the parts, then format it manually.

Comment: @AllanWind—using a semi–colon instead of a comma just separates it into two separate declarations as statements rather than two declarations as expressions in one statement (i.e. no practical difference).

Comment: @RobG acknowledged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let options = {
    timeZone: 'Europe/London',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric',
    hour12: false,
  },
  formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options);
  var date=formatter.format(new Date())
  var parts = formatter.formatToParts();
  console.log(parts)
  console.log(parts.find(c=>c.type=='hour').value);
  console.log(date)
```

Here you can check other parts also like minute and seconds.  resolvedOptions only returns the option value for formatting. For more details pls look here [intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the browser default language as the default, so you really have no idea what format the time will be.

Using the browser default might be OK in some cases, but it's nearly always not a good idea. Pages are presented in a particular language, so dates, numbers, etc. should follow the conventions of that language and not whatever random language the browser is set to (nearly always en-US for some unfathomable reason).

Also, the language setting often overrides options, particularly the *hour12* option. The best (i.e. most reliable and robust) approach is to manually format the time as required using *getHours*, *getMinutes* and *getSeconds* methods.

If you really want to use the Intl.DateTimeFormat constructor, then select a language that by default uses the format you want (the [CLDR project](http://cldr.unicode.org) can help, or just test various language tags). Test it thoroughly to ensure all implementations you are concerned with are consistent.

```js
function getEuropeTime(){
  return new Date().toLocaleString('en', {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: 'Europe/London'
  });
}

console.log(getEuropeTime());
```

Using *formatToParts* and manual formatting:

```js
function getEuropeTime(d = new Date()) {
  let {hour, minute, second} = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: 'Europe/London'
  }).formatToParts(d).reduce((acc, part) => {
    acc[part.type] = part.value;
    return acc;
  }, Object.create(null));
  return `${hour}:${minute}:${second}`;
}

console.log(getEuropeTime(new Date(Date.UTC(2020,12,12,15))));
```

Note that London observes daylight saving, but parts of Europe don't. Also, the EU is considering dropping daylight saving altogether so you might want to rename the function or use a different IANA representative location.